# Can you explicitly call the super class when using interface delegation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I using interface delegation as described [here](http://the-cogitator.com/2018/09/29/by-the-way-exploring-delegation-in-kotlin.html). Is there a way to use this but override and explicitly call the super class (delegate)?

Something along these lines (does not compile):

```
class Rect(val width: Int, val height: Int, position: Position) : Positionable by DefaultPositionable(position) {

    override fun getPosition() {
        val parent = super.getPosition()
        return parent.copy(x = parent.x + 1)    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `delegate` in that case. As workaround you can use next approach

```
class Rect(
    val width: Int,
    val height: Int,
    val pos: Position,
    private val positinable: Positionable = DefaultPositionable(pos)
) : Positionable by positinable {
    override fun getPosition(): Position {
        val parent = positinable.getPosition()
        return parent.copy(x = parent.x + 1)
    }
}
```